# Edit selected rows in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuejs2, vuetify.js

```js
editItem(){
    if(this.selected.length!=1) {
        alert("Choose only one row");
    } else {
        //what should i put in here?
    }
}
```

Hi, I created a datatable with selectboxs for each row using vuejs. 
I created a button that when clicked activates the method above, how can I make it that when just one row is selected a form is opened and you can edit the info in that row?

I made a form that when filled and a button "addItem" is clicked the data-table will insert the row with the info in the form.

I tried using v-edit-dialog but i just cant make it work...

here is the whole code:

```
<style>
table th + th { border-left:1px solid #dddddd; }
table td + td { border-left:1px solid #dddddd; }
</style>

<template>
  <div id="consulta">
      <v-container grid-list-xl fluid>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex sm12>
          <v-widget title="Testando">
            <div slot="widget-content">
              <v-container id="teste">
                <v-layout row>
                  <v-flex xs4>
                    <v-subheader>EAN</v-subheader>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs8>
                    <v-text-field
                      name="ean"
                      label=""
                      color="primary"
                      id="ean"
                      mask="#.######.######"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
                <v-layout row>
                  <v-flex xs4>
                    <v-subheader>Descrição</v-subheader>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs8>
                    <v-text-field
                      name="desc"
                      id="desc"
                      label=""
                      value=""
                      :rules="[(v) => v.length <= 50 || 'Max 50 characters']"
                      :counter="50"
                      single-line
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
                <v-layout row>
                  <v-flex xs4>
                    <v-subheader>Marca</v-subheader>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs8>
                    <v-text-field
                      name="marca"
                      label=""
                      color="primary"
                      id="marca"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
                <v-layout row>
                  <v-flex xs4>
                    <v-subheader>Departamento</v-subheader>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs8>
                    <v-text-field
                      name="dep"
                      label=""
                      color="primary"
                      id="dep"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
                <v-layout row>
                  <v-flex xs4>
                    <v-subheader>Categoria</v-subheader>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs8>
                    <v-text-field
                      name="categ"
                      label=""
                      color="primary"
                      id="categ"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
                <v-layout row>
                  <v-flex xs4>
                    <v-subheader>Atributos</v-subheader>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs8>
                    <v-text-field
                      name="att"
                      label=""
                      color="primary"
                      id="att"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
                <v-layout row>
                  <v-flex xs4>
                    <v-subheader>Loja</v-subheader>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs8>
                    <v-text-field
                      name="loja"
                      label=""
                      color="primary"
                      id="loja"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
                <v-layout row>
                  <v-flex xs4>
                    <v-subheader>URL</v-subheader>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs8>
                    <v-text-field
                      name="url"
                      label=""
                      color="primary"
                      id="url"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
             <div>
               <v-btn small color="primary" @click="addItem">Enviar</v-btn>
             </div>
             </v-container>
             </div>
             </v-widget>
            </v-flex>
        <v-flex sm12>
          <h1>Tabela</h1>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex lg12>
             <v-toolbar card color="white">
              <v-text-field
                flat
                solo
                prepend-icon="search"
                placeholder="Type something"
                v-model="search"
                hide-details
                class="hidden-sm-and-down"
              ></v-text-field>
              <v-btn icon>
                <v-icon>filter_list</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </v-toolbar>
            <v-divider></v-divider>   
          <v-card>
          <v-card-text class="pa-0">             
          <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :search="search"
            :items="items"
            item-key="ean"
            class="elevation-1"
            select-all
            v-model="selected">
            <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
            <td> <v-checkbox v-model="props.selected" primary hide-details></v-checkbox></td>
              <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.ean }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.desc }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.marca }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.dep }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.categ }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.att }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.loja }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.url }}</td>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
          <div>
             <v-btn color="red" @click="deleteItem">Delete</v-btn>
             <v-btn color="orange" @click="editItem">Edit</v-btn>
          </div>
        </v-flex>
           </v-layout>
          </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import API from '@/api';
  import EChart from '@/components/chart/echart';
  import MiniStatistic from '@/components/widgets/statistic/MiniStatistic';
  import PostListCard from '@/components/widgets/card/PostListCard';
  import ProfileCard from '@/components/widgets/card/ProfileCard';
  import PostSingleCard from '@/components/widgets/card/PostSingleCard';
  import WeatherCard from '@/components/widgets/card/WeatherCard';
  import PlainTable from '@/components/widgets/list/PlainTable';
  import PlainTableOrder from '@/components/widgets/list/PlainTableOrder';
  import VWidget from '@/components/VWidget';
  import Material from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors';
  import VCircle from '@/components/circle/VCircle';
  import BoxChart from '@/components/widgets/chart/BoxChart';
  import ChatWindow from '@/components/chat/ChatWindow';
  import CircleStatistic from '@/components/widgets/statistic/CircleStatistic';
  import LinearStatistic from '@/components/widgets/statistic/LinearStatistic';
  export default {
    layout: 'dashboard',
    components: {
      VWidget,
      MiniStatistic,
      ChatWindow,
      VCircle,
      WeatherCard,
      PostSingleCard,
      PostListCard,
      ProfileCard,
      EChart,
      BoxChart,
      CircleStatistic,
      LinearStatistic,
      PlainTable,
      PlainTableOrder
    },
    data() {
      return{
              search: '',
              selected: [],
              headers:[
              {text:'EAN', value:'ean', sortable: true, align:"center"},
              {text:'Descrição', value:'desc', sortable: true, align:"center"},
              {text:'Marca', value:'marca', sortable: true, align:"center"},
              {text:'Departamento', value:'dep', sortable: true, align:"center"},
              {text:'Categoria', value:'categ', sortable: true, align:"center"},
              {text:'Atributos', value:'att', sortable: true, align:"center"},
              {text:'Loja', value:'loja', sortable: true, align:"center"},
              {text:'URL', value:'url', sortable: true, align:"center"},
              ],
              items:[{
                  ean: '9234858583',
                  desc: 'Item teste',
                  marca: 'Danone',
                  dep: 'Comida?',
                  categ: 'Laticinio',
                  att: 'Yogurt',
                  loja: 'Mercadinho',
                  url: 'www.mercadinho.fakeaddress.com',
              }],
    }
    },
    methods: {
            addItem(){
             if(document.querySelector("#ean").value!=""&&
                document.querySelector("#desc").value!=""&&
                document.querySelector("#marca").value!=""&&
                document.querySelector("#dep").value!=""&&
                document.querySelector("#categ").value!=""&&
                document.querySelector("#att").value!=""&&
                document.querySelector("#loja").value!=""&&
                document.querySelector("#url").value!=""){
              let registro = {
                  "ean": document.querySelector("#ean").value,
                  "desc": document.querySelector("#desc").value,
                  "marca":document.querySelector("#marca").value,
                  "dep": document.querySelector("#dep").value,
                  "categ": document.querySelector("#categ").value,
                  "att": document.querySelector("#att").value,
                  "loja": document.querySelector("#loja").value,
                  "url": document.querySelector("#url").value,
              };
              this.insert(registro);
              this.items.push(registro)
             }
             else{
                 alert("Um ou mais campos não foram preenchidos!");
             }

          },
          editItem(){
           if(this.selected.length){
              alert("Select just one row")
            }
            else{
                 //show form to edit the info
            }
           },
          deleteItem(){
                  if(confirm("Deseja deletar tais fileiras?")){
                  for(var i = 0; i < this.selected.length; i++){
                       const index = this.items.indexOf(this.selected[i]);
                       this.items.splice(index, 1);
                       }
            }
          }
  }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo of what you've done so far on Codepen or Codesandbox (or similar)?

Comment: Added the whole code to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Vuetify as your Material Design Framework you could use the Dialog Component. You can find many Example in the official documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs#form

Comment: My button is calling a function in methods, it seems that I cant put v-model="" inside the <v-dialog> because it causes a error, what should I do then?

Comment: v-model needs a value which should be declared in data, just like your selected field in the datatable

Comment: I see, but how would I declare it?

Comment: Just look at the documentation I provided, you can see the source code of the examples by clicking on <view source>. There you will also see how the model is declared in the data section.